# Single Logout (SLO) for Salesforce Community using OIDC and Okta

Tags: community, customer-community, single-sign-on, open-id-connect, okta

**Background Context & Goal:**

Our end goal is to allow users to log in and log out of a salesforce community using okta credentials (via an openid auth. provider).
When customers logout of the community, they should be logged out of okta as well.
I created an auth provider of type OpenID that connects to Okta as an authorization server.

**Resources:**

- Salesforce - [Configure OpenID Connect SEttings for Single Logout Where Salesforce Is the Relying Party](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_auth_slo_oidc_rp_configuring.htm&type=5)

  - This documentation suggests that all you need to do is configure the custom logout url to the /logout endpoint for okta, and then update the okta logout redirect url to the auth. provider generated single logout url
- Okta - [Single Logout In Applications](https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/Apps/Apps_Single_Logout.htm)

  - This documentation suggests that it is necessary to  update the okta logout redirect url (as listed above by salesforce documentation) and that the relying party must make a get request in the format below
  - format:

> GET https://{baseUrl}/logout?id_token_hint=${id_token}&post_logout_redirect_uri=${post_logout_redirect_uri}&state=${state}

**Current state & issues:**

- State

  - ​​​​​​​Auth. provider custom logout is set
  - Okta app logout redirect is set to the slo auth. provider generated url
  - Auth. provider is set on community
  - User Profile component is set to have log in and logout actions in the community
- Issues

  - When we looked at what information was passed to okta, the request seemed to be missing all of the parameters listed in the okta get format
  - When I try to logout via the ootb logout button, the url shows the custom logout url and the page shows the following error:

> {"fault":{"faultstring":"Failed to Resolve Variable :
> policy(DecodeJWT_ParseIdToken)
> variable(request.queryparam.id_token_hint)","detail":{"errorcode":"steps.jwt.FailedToResolveVariable"}}}

**Questions:**

1. Do we need to create a custom logout component in order to set the variables/parameters lsited in the okta documentation get request? Or is that handled by the salesforce auth provider?
2. Is it possible to configure slo for an auth. provider that is connected to a community?  Or is this a format that salesforce is not compatible with?
3. If you have configured slo for a community before and have any resources or relevent documentation, could you please share? I have had trouble finding community specific slo information.

Comment: Sarah, did you ever find a solution for this? We're facing the same issue...